# Sigma Notation with Index

Tags: haskell, algebra, generalization

I've been trying to solve a problem that requires Sigma Notation (Or at least I think), but every implementation of Sigma Notation in Haskell i've come across doesn't use the index variable in its function. The particular formula i've been trying to replicate is:

[image]

It's used in calculating the number of trailing zeros in n!, but the best i've got is:

```
 sigma :: (Enum a, Num b) => a -> a -> (a -> b) -> b
 sigma i k fn = sum . map fn $ [i..k]

 zeros :: Int -> Int
 zeros n = sigma 1 n (???)
```

I'm trying to also create a general sigma function, that works with an index variable in f.
This works, but for 100!, it gives -11 trailing zeros. Overflow?

```
zeros :: Int -> Int
zeros n = sigma 1 n (\i -> n `div` 5 ^ i)
        where sigma i k fn = sum $ map fn [i..k]
```

P.S. Im on an in-browser IDE that limits compile time.  (So speed counts)

Comment: Isn't the `(???)` just `(\i -> floor (n / 5 ^ i))`? Assuming your formula meant to sum from `1` to `n`

Comment: I already tried that, and it doesn't work for me, and the error messages are cryptic.

Comment: /tmp/haskell114913-7-1k7mzh6/Zeros.hs:7:28:
    No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of `floor'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
    In the expression: floor (n / 5 ^ i)
    In the third argument of `sigma', namely
      `(\ i -> floor (n / 5 ^ i))'
    In the expression: sigma 1 n (\ i -> floor (n / 5 ^ i))

Comment: /tmp/haskell114913-7-1k7mzh6/Zeros.hs:7:37:
    No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `/'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
    In the first argument of `floor', namely `(n / 5 ^ i)'
    In the expression: floor (n / 5 ^ i)
    In the third argument of `sigma', namely
      `(\ i -> floor (n / 5 ^ i))'

Comment: If you're using `/` with `Int`, you're going to have a bad time.  Use `fromIntegral` to convert `Int` to a `Fractional` type which can be divided directly.  If you want integer division, you can use `div` instead.

Comment: @bheklilr Yep! My code was closer to pseudocode than Haskell.

Comment: i changed / to `div`, and floor to truncate: it rids an error, but now i've got one for truncate.

Comment: @Haskelier If that is the solution, please post it as such so others who have this particular problem find help and do not have to search the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your troubles are just coming from type mismatches.  You want to do the `truncate` at the very end and use fractional arithmetic for the division, exponentiation, and summation, and then truncate the result at the end.  Because of this, you'll need a bit more than just `zeros n = sigma 1 n something`:

```
zeros :: Integral a => a -> a
zeros n = truncate $ sigma 1 n (\i -> fromIntegral n / 5 ^ i)
```

The details here you need to worry about are the `fromIntegral n`, which converts `n` from an `Integral a => a` to a `Num b => b`, the `^` operator allows `Integral a => a` arguments as the exponent, so we don't need conversion there, and then `truncate` will convert back to an `Integral`.  We could make this signature even more general and return a different `Integral` that we inputted, but that's not really useful in practice.

So now we can input either `Int` or `Integer`, depending on how big of a number you need to input to this function (since you mentioned `100!`), but be warned that making a list of `100!` elements is going to seriously eat up RAM and CPU time.

If you're really wanting to compute the trailing zeros of a large number, it's probably going to be a lot easier to convert it to a string, as in:

```
zeros :: (Show a, Integral a) => a -> Int
zeros = length . takeWhile (== '0') . reverse . show
```

Comment: That last one with the string needs to compute the entire factorial, so it doesn't work just by nature of that enourmous number. (The first one doesn't work either because of the in-browser IDE's time limit.). I'm pretty sure that the problem requires some sort of advanced math that's beyond my capability.

Comment: @Haskelier How about `fac n = product [2..n]`, and `zeros = length . takeWhile (== '0') . reverse . show . fac`?

Comment: no, again to slow... All the comments are saying that there is some sort of mathematical trick to it, and that it's not what you think it is. (www.codewars.com)

Comment: @Haskelier Are you saying that it's still too slow?  Even running it in GHCi without optimizations on my computer I have to get up to `3000!` before it even takes ~0.02 seconds to compute.  It actually takes longer to print out `3000!` than it does to compute the number of trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1):

```
sigma i k fn = sum $ map fn [i..k]
zeros n = sigma 1 n (\i -> fromIntegral n / 5**(fromIntegral i))
```

Haskell does not automatically convert between integers and floating point numbers. That's why you need the `fromIntegral`.

Comment: It doesn't work, and it throws me this error:                Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> [c0]' with actual type `[b0]'
    In the return type of a call of `map'
    Probable cause: `map' is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `map fn [i .. k]'
    In the expression: sum . map fn [i .. k]                                At least on the in-browser interpreter im using.

Comment: My bad. I changed your `sigma` function but I forgot to replace the dot with a dollar. See the edit.

Comment: that works, but not for numbers above 100!. Could we add the type signature to allow it something bigger than Int? I dunno. See edit on post.

Comment: Why are you working with numbers above `100!`?  You aren't going to find any _computer_ that can efficiently handle a list of `100!` elements long.  That's a massive amount of number crunching.

Comment: I've got a website that is giving me a test case of 100!'s trailing zeros. I think there might be a more efficient formula...

Comment: I think there's some confusion.  The formula `f(n)` is is used in finding the number of trailing zeros in `n!`.  You wouldn't pass in `100!`, you would pass in `100`.